# Generate diagonal lines (stripes) in CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if it is possible to generate diagonal lines in css or svg to cover a div which will allow the background colour of the div to show through. Something like the following.

If anyone has an example that would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS Background Stripes on div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990812/css-background-stripes-on-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use base64 data as a png image.  For example:

```
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAQElEQVQYV2NkIAKckTrzn5GQOpAik2cmjHgVwhSBDMOpEFkRToXoirAqxKYIQyEuRSgK8SmCKySkCKyQGEUghQD+Nia8BIDCEQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
```

[This is a good generator](http://www.patternify.com/)

[An example of it at work](http://jsfiddle.net/J7Pv4/)

Answer (score 6):

You can try:

HTML:

```
<div class="deg45 stripes">TEST</div>
```

CSS3:

```
.stripes {
    height: 250px;
    width: 375px;
    -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
    -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-size: 50px 50px;
}
.deg45 {
    background-color: white;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, gray), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, gray), color-stop(.75, gray), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, gray 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, gray 50%, gray 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, gray 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, gray 50%, gray 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, gray 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, gray 50%, gray 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, gray 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, gray 50%, gray 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg, gray 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, gray 50%, gray 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fGykt/)

Where you can customize it to your needs as:

`-45deg` is the amount og the angle you want the stripes to have and `gray` the color of them. Also with `background-size` you can define the size of them

Comment: This doesn't work for all orientations. Using 55deg for example makes the pattern look tiled rather than striped. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes i did it on a btn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
 
     
  <button style=" background-size: 10px 10px; 
            background: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg,#606dbc,#606dbc 10px,#465298 10px,#465298 20px);
            height: 600%;"type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Large Default Button</button>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called stripe generator which solely purposes to create striped images.

http://www.stripegenerator.com/index.php

When done, tweak as required using the following css:

```
.stripes {
  background-image: url(/assets/images/stripe.png);
  background-position: 4px 0;
  background-size: 16px;
}
```