# Css 45 deg repeating lines

Tags: html, css

Result I wish in css

[image: Result I wish in css, please click this to view image]

I am working in a project and I need to display exactly like this a 45 deg lines repeating and a background of white, but I can't exactly figure it out

Comment: you can make an image with diagonal line and use it as background for the body. it will repeat itself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate diagonal lines (stripes) in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23628114/generate-diagonal-lines-stripes-in-css)

Comment: Yes , I tried it but  I want the stripe of 1px lines , can you please help me for that

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to it be element you can use 45deg line background pattern image
If need more help say